# Hide BAT file window when invoking it from Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I'm invoking the execution of a BAT file from Java with the Runtime object.

Is it possible to hide the BAT window during the execution of the script? How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try using javaw rather than java to run the script.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Update: Sorry, I think I read the question wrong.  I know I've suppressed a .bat window doing something along these lines before:

http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/56092-hide-the-command-prompt-windows/

Comment: It is not java what I want to execute, I want to execute an external BAT from Java (p.e: suppose I want to execute a BAT to change the name of the files of a folder)

Answer (score 1):

Invoke `start` as the first command in your process builder, with the `/b` option:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("start", "/b", "<mybatchcommand>");
// .. set environment, handle streams
builder.start();
```

The `/b` options suppresses the command window.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scriptName.vbs");
```

In scriptName.vbs you write

```
var WindowStyle_Hidden = 0
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
var result = objShell.Run("cmd.exe /c abc.bat", WindowStyle_Hidden)
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to create the WindowStyle_Hidden variable? IMO it would be easier to just do `cmd.exe /c abc.bat", 0`